# How to visually identify the drop target during drag and drop in Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, drag-and-drop, kendo-grid, draggable

I have a simple Kendo grid defined in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76sLggyL/).  I would like to drag and drop one row onto another.  That part does work.

However, while I am dragging the row, I want highlight the row underneath the dragged one to indicate to the user that if they were to drop it here - this is the row that would be replaced.

To that end, I handle `dragenter` and `dragleave` events on the grid.table.kendoDropTarget.  Unfortunately, it treats the entire grid as a drop target and only fires the event only once when I move the dragged item around the grid.

So my question is how to visual identify the row target of the drop during dragging operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're getting the wrong element to highlight. If you log inside `dragenter` the text of the `currentTarget` - with `$(e.draggable.currentTarget).find("td:first").text()` - you will notice that it only shows the value of the first column of the row you are dragging. The correct element to highlight is `e.dropTarget[0]` that changes as you move the dragged row.

Just change - in both `dragenter` and `dragleave` - this line:

```
e.draggable.currentTarget.addClass("highlight-droparea");
```

To this line:

```
$(e.dropTarget[0]).addClass("highlight-droparea");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76sLggyL/1/).

**UPDATE**

I didn't realize that in the above snippet drag/drop works only once. Trying to find out the issue I noticed that after first *drop* all rows lost their *draggable* attributes. So I wrapped both `kendoDraggable()` and `kendoDropTarget()` into a function and then, inside `kendoDropTarget.drop` event I call it again, re-creating all draggable events for the rows.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76sLggyL/2/).

I know that it isn't so pretty and it may decrease performance in some cases but I'm don't really know any other way for doing this.

Comment: I like what you've done, but for whatever reason, I can only drag and drop once.  The 2nd time, it just won't start the drag.

Comment: @AngryHacker I'm sorry, you're right. I didn't realize that. Check my update.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.  Any idea why it loses the draggable attributes?

Comment: @AngryHacker no. It re-creates all rows on drop - I know its crazy but you can expect anything from kendo - , maybe, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, thanks for your answer. Still I found this not working if you create new records in your grid: http://jsfiddle.net/76sLggyL/27/ .
You can just click "Add new record", hit cancel and you get drag&drop not working. The same issue I think would appear in all grid CRUD operations.

Comment: @Bounce yes, indeed it stops working. But you should create a new question pointing to this, describing your new problem. The problem you're having isn't related to what OP wants, ok ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, the problem I'm having is almost the same as OP (except I'm handling CRUD operations in my grid). So should I create new question for this? Because it may be treated as duplicate.

Comment: @Bounce it won't be, because it is in fact a different problem. OP's problem is about highlight the target drop row, and yours is about to stop working in a specific case. Post a new question relating this and your new problem. Besides, I can't answer by comments...

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown , got it. New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226777/kendo-ui-grid-dragdrop-stops-working-after-adding-new-record

Comment: @Bounce nice! I will take a break to look at it later.